# Will n vectors rotating with mutually different angular velocities always line up eventually?

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis

We‘re trying to prove linear independence of some basis for a function space and are stuck on the following problem:

Let $ e^{i(\omega_1 t + \theta_1)}, \dots,e^{i(\omega_n t + \theta_n)} $, where $ \omega_i, \theta_i \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\forall i,j \in \{1,\dots n \}: i \neq j \Rightarrow\omega_i \neq \omega_j$. Will there then always be a $t$ s.t. $\forall i,j \in \{1,\dots n \} \quad e^{i(\omega_i t + \theta_i)} = e^{i(\omega_j t + \theta_j)} $?
In other words if I have n vectors that all rotate with mutually different angular velocities, will they always eventually line up?

Comment: Hint: if the answer is yes, then the "alignment" repeats. What does this imply about the ratios between the $\omega_i$?

Comment: I really don’t know hahah, maybe another hint?:)

Comment: what do you know about modular artithmetic ?

Comment: Well it would mean that $((\omega_i t + \theta_i)$ mod $2 \pi)$=$\omega_j t + \theta_j$

Comment: What happens with $\omega_1=1$, $\omega_2=2$, $\omega_3=\sqrt2$, $\theta_1=\theta_2=0$, $\theta_3=\pi$?

Comment: @Karl I'm not sure I get what you mean. It seems to me that $e^{it}$, $e^{2it}$ and $e^{i\sqrt2 t}$ coincide only at $t=0$. Why should it repeat?

Comment: Ah so you’re saying that the first two being equal would imply that $t=2 \pi \mathbb{Z}$ but then we would have to find a $z \in \mathbb{Z}$ s.t. $(\sqrt{2}-1) z = k$ for $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ and that’s impossible, since that would imply that $\sqrt{2}$ is rational?

Comment: That was, indeed, the idea, Henry. I did not double check everything. But if you get the same conclusion :-)

Comment: Ok thank you! Is that the only problem, if we restrict the $\omega_i$ to be rational is it possible then?

Comment: This is a somewhat natural question. I think we have seen something similar on our site, but I could not find it. IIRC under some relatively mild conditions the phases "eventually line up within epsilon", and I may be conflating the two variants :-)